# WSO2 token generation using Token API failing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2-AM-1.9.0, trying to generate the Access token using Consumer Key and Consumer Secrete.
When making a call using CURL it works fine

```
    curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=testuser1&password=testUser1&scope=SANDBOX" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization:Basic ZXNuaHJTZmJmOW9XS28xTVM5UHJSZ1BacUU0YTpld040RGh1ZmsxYTNZbndVNU1uMVlGM3IwanNh" http://10.0.100.108:8280/token
```

But when trying with Java it returns 403 error code. Code is:

```
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://10.0.100.108:8280/token");
        HttpParams params=new BasicHttpParams();


        get.addHeader("Authorization","Basic ZXNuaHJTZmJmOW9XS28xTVM5UHJSZ1BacUU0YTpld040RGh1ZmsxYTNZbndVNU1uMVlGM3IwanNh");
        get.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        params.setParameter("grant_type", "password");
        params.setParameter("username", "testuser1");
        params.setParameter("password", "testUser1");
        params.setParameter("scope", "SANDBOX");

        get.setParams(params);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      String line = "";

      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
       responseBody = responseBody +"\n"+line;
      }


    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error:
        
        403 Status report
        Runtime Error No matching resource found in the API for the given request

Any help and info on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send a POST request not a GET. Use,

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.100.108:8280/token");
```